# Hello i am facing :: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: linux, awk

i am facing  error : syntax error near unexpected token `('

```
 EXIST= 'cat Test.csv | sed "1 d" | awk -F, '{ if ($4 != "999.999.999.999" && $4 != "99.99.99.99") {print $1}}' | sort |uniq | wc -l '
```

can anyone help?
when i run the same on terminal, it runs perfectly.
but when i try to run it in a script, gives me error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the input and actual and expected output/behavior and explain what you want to achieve. The space after  `EXIST=` and the quoting are probably wrong. Do you mean `EXIST=\`...\`` instead of `EXIST='...'`? I suggest to prefer `$(...)` over `\`...\``. (Probably everything could be implemented in an AWK script without of using other tools.)

Comment: yes , actually issue now resolved.
i was making a mistake between ' and `.

thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

copy/paste every shell script you write into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about until you learn the basics and certainly before posting a question containing such a script on this forum. It's frustrating to us when people post scripts that contain errors that a tool can detect.

In addition to the errors shellcheck will tell you about - you don't need `cat` or `sed` when you're using `awk` and `sort | uniq` = `sort -u` but in any case your whole pipeline could be reduced to one awk script:

```
exist=$( awk -F, '(NR>1) && ($4 !~ /^(999?\.){3}999?$/) && !seen[$1]++{cnt++} END{print cnt+0} Test.csv)' )
```

Also see [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) for why I'm using `exist` instead of `EXIST` as the variable name.

The fact you're storing that count of unique `$1`s in a variable named `exist`, though, makes me wonder if you really need it to hold a count at all.